# Rxjs ReplaySubject initializing with 'null' value before being emitted - Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I want to create a subject without initial value.
I have created a `ReplaySubject` that buffers only the last value that been emitted.
The problem is that on the subscription is giving a `null` as initial value before it's being emitted.

My service:

```
 private _replaySubjects = new ReplaySubject<Project>(1);
 public replaySubjectAsObservable$ = this._replaySubjects.asObservable();
```

My component:

```
 this.subjectSub = someService._projectList$.subscribe(value => {
            console.log(value)
  });
```

Rxjs version - 6.5.2

Comment: Replay subject with 1 saved value is BehaviorSubject. Behavior subject must hold a value.

Comment: ReplaySubject that buffers all values that been emitted

Comment: Your understanding or ReplaySubject is correct. It will not emit an initial value and will emit the last value to new subscribers. Can you show more of your code?

Comment: Its been 3 years and I just stumbled upon this. I have a feeling you were using `ReplayBubject` inside a switchMap or similar concatenation and it was creating undesired results

Answer (score 0):

This won't emit any value until a significant value is emitted with `this._replaySubject.next(newProject)`.

It has the added benefit that you can access the last emitted value outside of a subscription with `this._replaySubject.getValue()`.

```
private _replaySubjects = new BehaviorSubject<Project>(null);
public replaySubjectAsObservable$ = this._replaySubjects.asObservable().pipe(skipWhile(project => project === null || project === undefined));;
```

Comment: Except now it won't emit any other null or undefined values either.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but is don't answering my question.As i understand ReplaySubject shouldn't send any values to the subscriptions before it being emitted by .next(). My question was, why there is an initial value of null before the .next() was called ?

Comment: @Igor.r I just tried your case and it does not emit a first null value. Could you share a minimal StackBlitz or similar that shows your problem?